# PHP drop down menu for my get_category child of

Tags: php, menus, dropdown, categories

I have this code here and I can't figure out how to get it within a drop down menu.

```
<H3>Availabilities</H3>
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';

// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids,
        'child_of' => 61,

    ) );

    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // Display post categories.
    echo  $terms;


} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `wp_dropdown_categories()` instead of `wp_list_categories()`, if you dont *need* to use the list function.

`wp_dropdown_categories()` seems to be working just like the list function. So first just try and replace these two functions.

```
$terms = wp_dropdown_categories( array( ...
```

Read about it in the codex [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/).

Comment: I got it working. How do I make them clickable links?

Comment: So I guess you want to go to the term archive URL if you select a term from the drop down?  Actually this is not possible with just the function `wp_dropdown_categories` alone, or I should say, this is not how select/dropdown menus work. So this isnt really a WordPress question.  Anyway you either need a _form_ and a _submit-button_ or you need some _javascript/jQuery_ to fire an `onchange`.   _Please take a look at the (old) codex page of `wp_dropdown_categories` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories), as there are multiple examples of what you want._